# Word VBA: How to check if the window "in focus" is a protected view or not

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

In my Word VBA AutoOpen Sub, I want to check if the opened document has been opened "normally" or if it has been opened in protected view.

However, if I use `ThisDocument.Application.ActiveWindow`, it will throw an error in case a document has been opened in protected view, as the protected view doesn't count as an `ActiveWindow` object.

And the other way around, if I want to use `ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Active` this returns `True` if the document has been opened in protected view, but if the document is opened in "standard" view, then there is no `ActiveProtectedViewWindow` object, so it throws an error.

Is there any property that I can check, so that I immediately know in which mode the document has been opened? Or do I really have to work with `On Error GoTo` and basically sort out the errors?

Also, is there any way to change the zoom factor of a protected view document? I couldn't find any property that would allow that.

Comment: If the document is in protected mode, it could be (not sure) that it adds something to the Window title. You could check for that. Keep in mind that if you work with non-english clients, this may be written differently depending on what language people use.

Comment: @LPChip I was also thinking about that, but then how do you access the caption? Because I'd usually get that through `ActiveWindow.Caption`, so it throws an error if the document is in protected view. Can I get the caption from a "universal" window object that doesn't differentiate between active and protected?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the document is in protected mode, does any VBA macro work? For example, can you still do an `msgbox("test")`?

Comment: @LPChip Yes, if I put the code into the AutoOpen Sub, it will execute.

Comment: instead of `On Error GoTo`, you can simply use `On Error Resume Next`. Then, retrieve any property of the `ActiveWindow` (for instance `ActiveWindow.Document.Name`) and if the result is empty, do the same for `ActiveProtectedViewWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `On Error Resume Next`, and simply try one. If it doesn't provide a result, try the other one.

A simple example:

```
Sub identifyActive()
Dim t As String
On Error Resume Next
    t = ActiveWindow.Document.Name & " - not protected"
If t = "" Then
    t = ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Document.Name & " - protected"
End If
Debug.Print t ' you probably want to do something else with the result
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. I was aware of the On Error options but I find this a very unpleasing solution, since I actively have to work with an error instead of a property. Looks like there is no property for what I'm trying to do :/